# IOS carthage related build issue in Xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, payment-gateway, carthage

Carthage update command failed with exit code 65:

[image]

Ios buid error

[image]

Comment: Which version of Carthage do you use? Maybe [this](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Xcode12Workaround.md) helps. Or update Carthage

Comment: Carthage Version  0.38.0

Comment: Then, can you call `carthage update --use-xcframeworks`. This flag special for Xcode 12.X versions

Comment: Still same error. Build Failed
        Task failed with exit code 65: